# Command-line tool to ask remote server for current date-time

Tags: macos, command-line, ntp

On Mac OS X (such as 10.8 thru 10.11) is there a bundled [command-line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_interface) tool to ask a specific remote [NTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol) [time server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_server) for the current date-time?

I found [`ntpdc`](http://www.unix.com/man-page/FreeBSD/8/ntpdc/) but this queries the `ntpd` utility which I assume means going through my already-defined NTP servers. I want to make a call outside of my pre-defined NTP servers.

Like this imaginary line where `-s` means server-address:

```bash
ntpclient -s time.euro.apple.com current
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can use `sntp` as standard query tool for either NTP or [SNTP](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol#SNTP) servers. You may get, set or adjust the time on your host with it.

E.g.

```
sntp time.euro.apple.com
```

shows the time

```
sntp -d time.euro.apple.com
```

shows a more verbose response including the current time.

Check [man sntp](http://web.archive.org/web/20150923114547/https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/sntp.1.html) or in the shell `man sntp` for more options.

Comment: Link to manpage is 404 now